# Redirect old VBulletin link to Xenforo 1.5

Tags: .htaccess, vbulletin, xenforo

I need help to solve this.
My old vb forum link format:

```
http://forum.olddomain.com/showthread.php?t=345394&p=26215794&viewfull=1#post26215794
```

My new xf post link format:

```
https://forum.newdomain.com/posts/26215794/
```

My old domain is now on different server and htaccess only.

How to make htacces redirection for case above?
Curently I'm using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+-([\d]+).html showthread.php?t=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule [^/]+/([\d]+)-.+.html showthread.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/showthread.php?t=/(.*)$ https://forum.newdomain.com/threads/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/showthread.php?s=&p=/(.*)$ https://forum.newdomain.com/posts/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work, and I got

```
The requested URL /showthread.php was not found on this server.
```

So how to solve it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a / when configuring this in .htaccess context, that has been stripped off at that point already. And RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only - if you want to check/match anything in the query string, you need to use a RewriteCond to do so.

Comment: @04FS any RewriteCond example to enlighten me? sorry this is my first case so I don't really understand to solve. thank you!

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/

Comment: @04FS thank you for your help. still I can't find the way to solve this case. I'll try to find some another way. thanks!

Comment: you may want to try https://xenforo.com/community/resources/vbulletin-4-x-url-redirection.120/ and https://xenforo.com/community/resources/redirection-scripts-for-vbulletin-3-x.264/